# Edit an existing GCal invite

Tags: buttons, labels, calendar

I have an application that allows the user to send out a GCal invite. Within the page, there is a button that says, "Create GCal invite."

For the time being, to keep the scope small, this button just links out to a GCal invite page where some of the fields are pre-filled (invite title, description, etc.)

Question:

After the invite is sent, the button label changes to, "Edit GCal invite." This allows the user to edit an already sent invite should they need to make changes to it. Is the label (Edit...) enough to communicate that the invite has, in fact, already been sent?

Note that there isn't a concept of draft invites - ie, a user can't create an invite now and save it for later. So not sure if it makes sense to denote elsewhere the invite status eg - no invite, invite sent - seems to just be adding noise.

Comment: It'd be great if you can share the rough mockups of what you're describing

Answer (score 1):

A (rough) mock-up would help.

This depends on your user population, I'd say. Looking at my mom, I'd definitely prefer to have a separate indication ("Sent" somewhere). Looking at a screen which is mostly for other tasks, invites being a side function, and the user working with this screen for most of her day, I'd probably go with the indication by the button texts.

By the way, once "Edit invite" has been clicked, the next page/dialog can make it clear that the invite was sent. If there's an easy Cancel button, that's a way to keep the main screen cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Checking out how Invites are sent and managed on other popular applications like Slack etc would help you get an idea of a clean flow. Sharing access to google docs is another good example.

Difficult to help with an empty table between you and us.